# Is there a way to automaticly change wordpress category of last post

Tags: wordpress, date, categories

I have an portfolio in wordpress. 
What i want to do is that the last 3 posted portfolio posts that they have an category called last-gaming-news. the other post dont need any category

Is there an plugin for that? or some php code.

Comment: I can code the custom code if you want, (paid)

Comment: How much would that cost me?

Comment: you can contact me at: http://codingbots.com/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is :

- get rid of this category for all posts first (because I guess you want this category **only** for the three last posts, right?)
- select the three latest posts and give them the category you want

I suggest:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'custom_function');

function custom_function(){
    $posts = get_posts([ 
          'post_type'        => 'portfolio'
            ]);

    foreach ($posts as $post){
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, 'last-gaming-news', 'types' );
    }

    $args = [ 'orderby'          => 'date',
          'order'            => 'DESC',
          'post_type'        => 'portfolio',
          'post_status'      => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'   => 3 ];

    $latest3posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach( $latest3posts as $post ){
        wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, 'last-gaming-news', 'types', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank but this is for normal post right? I need it for portfolio posts. or is that the same thing

Comment: If your portfolio post is a custom post type, you need to get the slug of this Custom post type, and then give it to the functions. I've edited with the 'portfolio' slug.

Comment: i dont know exactly how it works. since its in my team. but basicly on the left bar it says portfolio and then add item and then i can type something.
One more question. in what php script should i putt this? and will it be called automaticly or do i need to write code for that?

Comment: If you have a custom theme, copy and paste this code in your functions.php file. Else you will have to paste this code into a custom plugin (which can be not so difficult). But it's another subject , you ought to read the codex page about plugin creation. WordPress uses filters and actions to hook into some place at a time in the execution of WordPress. In this code, it 's the "add_action" part that triggers the custom function on the WordPress "init" action. For the portfolio slug I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: To find the slug, in your admin area, go to porfolio > all items. The page that displays has a paramater in its url which looks like `post-type=toto`. Now you have your cpt slug.

Comment: the parameter it says is this
post_type=portfolio

So i think that code is good right or not?

Comment: I think that this doesnt work. Maybe it is because of the init but when i do putt the code in nothing happens to my portfolio posts.

Comment: I also see right now that the portfolio uses types instead of categorys but i dont know how to access them

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "uses types instead of categories"? You mean it does not use the "category" taxonomy? Well then instead you ought to use the name of the taxonomy ( "types"?) instead of "category" into the above code.

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as accepted, I shall be rewarded for this! - cheers - ps I will update the code for it to be exact